# Pandas plotting graph with timestamp

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

pandas 0.23.4
python 3.5.3

I have some code that looks like below

```
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime

from matplotlib import pyplot


def dateparse():
    return datetime.strptime("2019-05-28T00:06:20,927", '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S,%f')


series = pd.read_csv('sample.csv', delimiter=";", parse_dates=True,
                     date_parser=dateparse, header=None)
series.plot()
pyplot.show()
```

The CSV file looks like below

```
2019-05-28T00:06:20,167;2070
2019-05-28T00:06:20,426;147
2019-05-28T00:06:20,927;453
2019-05-28T00:06:22,688;2464
2019-05-28T00:06:27,260;216
```

As you can see `2019-05-28T00:06:20,167` is the timestamp with milliseconds and 2070 is the value that I want plotted.

[image]

When I run this the graph gets printed however on the X-Axis I see numbers which is a bit odd. I was expecting to see actual timestamps (like MS Excel). Can someone tell me what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You did not set datetime as index. Aslo, you don't need a date parser, just pass the columns you want to parse:

```
dfstr = '''2019-05-28T00:06:20,167;2070
2019-05-28T00:06:20,426;147
2019-05-28T00:06:20,927;453
2019-05-28T00:06:22,688;2464
2019-05-28T00:06:27,260;216'''

df = pd.read_csv(pd.compat.StringIO(dfstr), sep=';', 
                 header=None, parse_dates=[0])


plt.plot(df[0], df[1])
plt.show()
```

Output:

[image]

Or:

```
df.set_index(0)[1].plot()
```

gives a little better plot:

[image]